# Can I compare two sets of data to find the probability of one set of data being higher?

Tags: probability, distributions

If I have two sets of data, find the probability that one set of data will have a higher value

i.e. for sets A and B:
if you took one random variable from each set, one is more likely to be greater
than the other.

Is this possible? And if so, how can it be done?

Comment: Is this not the random variable $B - A$?

Comment: Search for discussions on 'stochastic dominance' and see if that matches what you have in mind. // Are your data approximately normal, following some other type of continuous distribution, or are they essentially ordinal categorical (for example, Likert scores)? Knowing that much might help give a useful answer.